# Issue setting default profile pic in Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new to Swift/iOS development, so this might be a stupid question, but I can't seem to find how to do this correctly.

I am following a youtube guide on how to programmatically code (no storyboard) a login screen in Swift and register a user into a Firebase database. The basic outline of the design are as follows

[image]

Once the user clicks the icon of the **cat with the crown**, the image picker comes up and they can select a profile picture and then register like normal. If the user does not select an image from the picker, the **cat with the crown** icon gets loaded as the profile picture by default.

What I have been trying to do is make it so a different picture (not the cat, and not shown to the user on the login page) named **"nedstark"** is set as the default profile picture that is stored in the database.

The program uses LoginController.swift and LoginController + handlers.swift files to make this happen. I tried to add a conditional to the picker where if nothing is selected, the default profile pic is set to a specific default user pic (different than the cat), but it doesn't work.

**This is the code that stores the photo and other User info into the Database**

```
            let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child("\(imageName).jpg")

        if let profileImage = self.profileImageView.image, let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 0.1) {

            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }

                if let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {

                    let values = ["name": name, "email": email, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]

                    self.registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUID(uid, values: values as [String : AnyObject])
                }
            })
        }
```

**This is the code where I am trying to set the default profile pic**

```
func handleSelectProfileImageView() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
    } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
    }
    else {  //Testing if default profile pic set
        selectedImageFromPicker = UIImage(named: "nedstark")
    }

    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
        profileImageView.image = selectedImage
    }
    else {  //Testing if default profile pic set
        profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "nedstark")
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I 
I know that this is a total noob question, but any help, tips, or pointers is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle delegate method of cancel event. UIImagepickercontrolledelegate has another method 
***imagePickerControllerDidCancel()***

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "nedstark")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When you click on cancel button in pickerviewcontroller then ***didfinishPickingMedia*** function won't call. That's way your default image is not set when you tap on cancel button.

Comment: Thanks! This worked in a sense, but what if the user never clicks on the Cat Icon and never selects the Image Picker. Is there any way to set the default image (overriding the existing Cat image without actually changing it as the header photo)?

Comment: when you want to change image from cat to default

Comment: Yes, but I don't want it to be visible to the user. So like, I want the default image to be uploaded to the Firebase database in place of the cat icon that is visible by the user (currently, if the user doesn't select an image at all, the code uploads the cat icon as the users profile picture).

Comment: create a bool variable isPicSelected and set it true in didFinishPickingMedia () and false in didcancel() function. When you send data to firebase than check the value of isPicSelected variable and send defalut pic if isPicselected bool has false value.